# gulp sourcemaps generating last scss file only

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I am new to gulp plugins and am trying to get sourcemaps to work

file structure

```
css/
   sass/
       theme/
            _some-style.scss
            _some-style-2.scss
            _some-style-3.scss
       style.scss
   style.css
   style.css.map
```

In my style.scss file I have

```
@import "theme/some-style";
@import "theme/some-style-2";
@import "theme/some-style-3";
```

great so I am only getting, _some-style-3.scss to appear in my dev tools when I inspect. I know I have a path issue here but not sure how to fix it.

Gulp file:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
   return gulp.src(css/sass/theme/**/*.scss)
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(css));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is a bit confusing as you have different paths in your file structure, your import statements, and your gulp file. I'll base my answer on the path you provided in the file structure.

1. Your file structure says "theme" is directly under "sass", so your @import statement should be `@import "theme/_various-scss-file.scss"`
2. You need to specify the scss file in gulp.src not just the path, for example `gulp.src('css/sass/style.scss')`. And output path, according to your file structure and assume your gulp file is in the same folder as the css folder, should be `gulp.dest('css')`.

Comment: wow, yeah  so tired when I wrote this. It should be updated to represent what I actually have now.

Comment: if you've already imported the other files into style.scss then you just need to specify that file in gulp.src. Like this: `return gulp.src(css/sass/style.scss)`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Unrelated to paths. I didn't include that I was also compressing my scss first and that is interfering with the sourcemapping